# Can this MS Word Macro be amended so the blank lines in the AddressLine bookmarks are deleted?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've created a macro for work where a letter template prompts users to enter info into text boxes to update the document. The problem I have is some clients have addresses over 3 lines, some over 5 etc, and the macro leaves blank lines for any bookmarks not populated. Is there a way to amend this macro so the empty lines are deleted?

Thanks

I tried entering a multiline address field option into the macro, but I couldn't get it to work.

```
Sub LetterTemplate()

    Dim bookmarkName As String
    Dim bookmarkText As String
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Set the bookmark names in your template
    Dim bookmarkNames As Variant
    bookmarkNames = Array("Name", "TitleSurname", "AddressLine1", "AddressLine2", "AddressLine3", "Postcode", "AccountNumber") ' Add or remove bookmark names as needed

    ' Loop through each bookmark
    For i = LBound(bookmarkNames) To UBound(bookmarkNames)
        ' Prompt for text to insert
        bookmarkName = bookmarkNames(i)

        If bookmarkName = "AddressBookmark" Then
            ' For multiline address field, use InputBox with vbOKCancel and vbInformation
            bookmarkText = InputBox("Enter address for " & bookmarkName & ":", "Enter Address", , , , vbInformation + vbOKCancel)

            ' Check if the user clicked OK
            If bookmarkText = vbOKCancel Then
                ' Insert text into the bookmark
                Call InsertIntoBookmark(bookmarkName, bookmarkText)
            End If
        Else
            ' For other bookmarks, use the standard InputBox
            bookmarkText = InputBox("Enter text for " & bookmarkName & ":", "Enter Text")

            ' Insert text into the bookmark
            Call InsertIntoBookmark(bookmarkName, bookmarkText)
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "Action Complete"

End Sub

Sub InsertIntoBookmark(bookmarkName As String, bookmarkText As String)
    Dim bmRange As Range

    ' Check if bookmark exists
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName) Then
        ' Set the range to the bookmark
        Set bmRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range

        ' Clear existing content in the bookmark
        bmRange.Text = ""

        ' Insert the new text into the bookmark
        bmRange.Text = bookmarkText

        ' Extend the bookmark to cover the inserted text
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, bmRange
    Else
        MsgBox "Bookmark '" & bookmarkName & "' not found.", vbExclamation, "Bookmark Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider using a UserForm to get the data, instead.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove blank line (paragraph) and bookmark if user input (bookmarkText) is blank.
- The line `bmRange.Text = ""` is not necessary.

```vb
Sub InsertIntoBookmark(bookmarkName As String, bookmarkText As String)
    Dim bmRange As Range, oBM As Bookmark
    ' Check if bookmark exists
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName) Then
        Set oBM = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName)
        ' Set the range to the bookmark
        Set bmRange = oBM.Range
        If Len(bookmarkText) = 0 Then
            ' Remove bookmark
            oBM.Delete
            ' Remove paragraph
            bmRange.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
        Else
            ' Insert the new text into the bookmark
            bmRange.Text = bookmarkText
            ' Extend the bookmark to cover the inserted text
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, bmRange
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Bookmark '" & bookmarkName & "' not found.", vbExclamation, "Bookmark Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @taller, but changing the Macro to this causes a Run-time error '5825' at `oBM.Delete` when trying to skip an address line.

Comment: Try the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for trying @taller, but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: I have tested it w/o issue with M365. You can just remove/comment it.

Comment: What's the error text?

Comment: No error text but it kept the lines that should be removed, and deleted ones that were populated. No probs - I'll probably try the UserForm solution suggested above.

Comment: Assumes `AddressLine3` is blank line. Please try `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AddressLine3").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select` to check if the selection is the blank line. If not, please upload a screenshot in your post.